# Creating a new dictionary in Swift - when to use which method.

Tags: swift

I see it is possible to create dictionaries in swift as follows

```
var dict1 = [String: Int]()
var dict2 = Dictionary<String, Int>()
```

and then use it as normal. When should I use which method of creating dictionaries?

Comment: Essentially the same question (and answer) as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240602/difference-between-string-and-arraystring (only for dictionaries instead of arrays).

Comment: My Google-fu was not strong enough to find it but perhaps having another example will help people stumble upon this answer in their searches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apple produced book "The Swift Programming Language" says

> The type of a Swift dictionary is written in full as Dictionary<Key, Value>, where Key is the type of value that can be used as a dictionary key, and Value is the type of value that the dictionary stores for those keys.
>
> You can also write the type of a dictionary in shorthand form as [Key: Value]. Although the two forms are functionally identical, the shorthand form is preferred and is used throughout this guide when referring to the type of a dictionary.

so it seems that the shorthand form is preferred. Probably because it looks a bit cleaner.